# Coupling and Cohesion in database design

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, software-design

Say there are two modules users and status. I split these modules in following 2 cases
Here is **case-1**
[image]

Here is **case-2**
[image]

I am trying to understand which database design lowly coupled and should be adopted according to the Software Engineering Design principals? Particularly interested to have comments that which approach is better by considering **re-usability**. I mean in future which approach can be re-used easily & effectly to any other software design

Comment: Table names should be singular.  User & Department.

Comment: What is the **relationship** between department, status, and option?  You don't have options in case-2.

Comment: @LifeSaver you seem to be confusing systems modeling with data modeling.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes because in case-2 status is storing status option of a particular department. thus in case-2 I renamed option table as status

Comment: @reaanb How I am unable to understand system modeling with data modeling. Please be more specific. You may be right person to clear my concepts

Comment: @LifeSaver Systems modeling is about organizing a solution system into functional parts.  These parts may have state (OOP is for building state machines) but the focus is on useful behavior and interaction towards a goal.  Cohesion and coupling are important concepts here to keep the parts focused and limit the ripples of change.  Data modeling is about organizing a problem or body of knowledge in terms of simple facts.  It focuses on what the system (or a component) knows rather than what it does, and here we focus on dependencies and normalization to keep the model neat.

Comment: can you please give me some examples to clear my concepts

Comment: @reaanb I changed the case-2 diagram. Please review it

Answer (score 1):

Both your cases have **consistency** issues rather than coupling/cohesion issues.

First, both your cases allow for a department to have a limitless amount of statuses. This might not make sense if, for instance, the status represents whether the department is open or closed. If departments may only have 1 status at any given time, your primary key for an status must be dept_id (in which case it should be within the departments table as a foreign key to the table with the available statuses instead), this may be incorrect depending on what you are modelling. The second case, however, is worse for **consistency** because it allows you to have an unlimited amount of values for the variable status (There is no table to define the valid values for status, so this case allows you to have typos even, for instance a department with status "opne" instead of "open")

Secondly, the users table has no relationship with the rest of the data, which may not make sense again (users can't be members of any department, etc). In the first case, users have no status and in the second case it is related to an status table... Neither case (for the users table) has more or less coupling than the other (because it has no relationship with anything else in your model), but you need to check whether you want users to have an status (and what is that status, whether it should be selected from a fixed list of values or not).

We don't have much to go on about analyzing coupling/cohesion in both of your cases. You must better understand what you are trying to model and should first worry about ensuring [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)).

Here's an short but interesting blog post about coupling/cohesion if you want to read some: https://thebojan.ninja/2015/04/08/high-cohesion-loose-coupling/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. very valid but doesn't have any result of your discussion. If my both models are not good then what should be there in place.

Comment: If you elaborate on what you are trying to model I can edit it and add that to the answer. You asked which model is best when it comes to coupling/cohesion/reusability and I answered that neither is because there are consistency issues and we don't have enough information about what we are modelling.

Comment: I just given 2 easy examples to understand how the modules should be designed. Here in my question if we say low coupling and high cohesion then which model will be better in provided two cases. If neither then give me an example how to set 2/3 modules e.g. departments, status and users

Comment: I replaced the case-2 picture. Please recheck my question

Comment: Your changed image added more confusion. Now we have a new element called "profile", but the difference between user and profile is not clear. When I state we do not have enough information I mean we don't know what you are trying to model: 1. We don't know the purpose of this database (could be an employee/company database or a university department/student or contributor database). 2. We don't know the rules of the database (it's not clear whether departments may have more than one status, what status means and what is the relation between users and departments)

Comment: My aim is not to show you database and its problem but sorting advise regarding moduler design. for example there are two modules users and profile then connectivity between modules is okay or not

Comment: You must first determine what is the problem you are trying to solve with the database before you are able to determine which design is best. You may relate two or more database tables in several different ways and all of them may be correct and efficient depending on the problem you are trying to solve. All I can do with the info I have is point out consistency issues which may happen in both cases you've shown regardless of which problem they are meant to solve, which is what I did.